# Can't run a specific version of node on openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am following the steps described in [this](https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-custom-version-openshift) repository but I can't seem to make it work. When I look into my [env](http://staticshin-brislinkblog.rhcloud.com/env) file the nodejs version is still .6.20

My node js version file is the default one, so the node version .8.9 should be running. Any idea why this is happening?

My marker file:

```
0.8.9
```

Debug output when I try to start my application

```
==> nodejs/logs/node.log <==

npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message application-name@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/51ba8386e0b8cd2873000002/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-        debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 1
```

Just for the sake of completeness. My package.json file

```
{

"name": "application-name",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node server.js"
 },

"dependencies": {

    "express": "3.2.5",
    "mustache": "*",
    "request" : "*",
"buildify":"*",
"cheerio" : "*",
"slugs" : "*",
"to-markdown":"*",
"consolidate":"*"
  }
}
```

The [app](https://github.com/brislink/specter) runs locally just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this version of the nodejs starter code better: https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift

It contains a newer version of the `.openshift` application build hooks for nodejs.  It will read the Marker file, but also has support for reading directly from your `package.json` file's `engines` attribute to compile your Nodejs runtime.

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 0.10.0",
  "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
},
```

I'm hoping to [get this merged in](https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/pull/3) as the default `.openshift` folder content for all nodejs apps on OpenShift.

You'll also want to make sure that you are binding to the ***NEW*** environment variables: `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` and `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`.  These were recently renamed.

I usually add something like this to my application code, allowing it to run anywhere:

```
var ip_addr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '8080';
```

OpenShift currently shows you the output from `npm start`, which may not reveal all of your application's output.  For additional debugging info, you could try starting your app manually:

1. First, stop your app from the command line: `rhc app stop APP_NAME`
2. Then, connect to your application gear / container `rhc ssh APP_NAME`
3. `cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`
4. and manually run whatever command is defined within your `package.json` file's `scripts.start` attribute.

Hopefully that gives you a bit more visibility into what is going on.

Comment: The repository you referenced here https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/pull/3 appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. There are subtle differences. See also the comments.

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style

Comment: Thanks. I did not read the comments. But I read the article. I think I need to take a more closer look

Answer (score 1):

Did you see anything like this in your "git push" output?

```
remote:   - Checking to see if Node.js version 0.8.9 is installed ... 
remote:   - Downloading and extracting http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.9/node-v0.8.9-linux-x64.tar.gz ... 
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 100 4578k  100 4578k    0     0  31.4M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33.8M
```

and towards the bottom of the bottom, something like:

```
remote:   - Using Node.js version 0.8.9, checking app URI ... 
remote:   - test URI = http://mynode-sannam.rhcloud.com/env
remote:   - Version from test URI = 
remote: 
remote:   - Checking to see if Node.js version 0.8.9 is installed ...
```

I tried the same instructions and it seems to have worked. Check my env here: http://mynode-sannam.rhcloud.com/env

Please redo your steps one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will redo it and keep an eye on these messages.

Comment: It worked. I just re-installed it from scratch.Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry I spoke too soon. In my git push response I have `done installing node.js version 0.8.9` but it is still .6.2.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i need to look at your it push output and also contents of your marker file. You can send them to sannam@redhat.com

Comment: Doesn't work here. The git push output still print `remote: npm info using node@v0.6.20`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and on the beginning i wasn't able to solve it using source code from https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift, but reading the push output I noticed some permission problems.
So for other people that is having the same issue, just go into:

```
cd .openshift\action_hooks
```

and run this command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x *
```

It gives the permissions to run commands that upgrades node version

Comment: This git command gives all sorts of errors for me: error: .openshift/action_hooks/build: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: Unable to process path .openshift/action_hooks/build

Comment: seems like some files in action_hooks are not in the index try to add the --add flag to the command