# How to update npm on an OpenShift gear?

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

How can I update npm on OpenShift?

I'm having problems while deploying because npm started using ^1.2.3 version notations and it's not compatible with the current npm in my application:

```
remote: npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: through@'^2.3.4'
remote: npm ERR! Valid install targets:
remote: npm ERR! ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","1.0.0","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","2.0.0","2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.4","2.2.5","2.2.6","2.2.7","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.4"]
```

Is there a way of fixing this, or I'll have to go back to outdated packages?

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift does not provide root access to developers, but you can still select a custom version of npm by [running your own nodejs binary in user space](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift).

Developers can also [package up their own custom nodejs cartridge](https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges), allowing teams to define and standardize their dependencies in a reusable way.

Here is an answer that helps you [run a custom version of Nodejs on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093167/cant-run-a-specific-version-of-node-on-openshift/17115166#17115166)

You can also try [working with user-defined npm globals on OpenShift](https://twitter.com/ryanj/status/448932500610355201)