# Should I stop node server before a git push? Can I update node on Openshift?

Tags: node.js, git

## Dear community!

I have a few questions regarding my Openshift site with Node.js.
 I'm kind of starting out so please be simplistic and clear.

- ***Am I supposed to stop server.js on Openshift before a git push?***
  I'm asking this, because sometimes it takes so long to complete a git push or it doesn't even complete so I stop it after 5 or so mins.
- ***Can I update node and/or npm?***
  `Node: v0.10.35`, `npm: 1.4.28`. The current versions on my mac is `node: v5.3.0` and `npm: 3.5.2`. I'd really like to update, but couldn't find anything to get started.

Please clear my head if I shouldn't do this or point me in the direction if it's possible.

Comment: if i remember right, when you push. openshift will automatically stop the server, apply the changes, and then start the server back up. Ive just pushed to a node site with out stopping it first and had no troubles.

Comment: this should help with updating node and npm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788457/how-to-update-npm-on-an-openshift-gear

Comment: Okay then I won't worry about stopping the server. I'm checking the link tomorrow. Thanks a lot!